# print value of new variable from two combined variables in PHP

Tags: php

There are two variable, but one is translated of the other. Now i want to print translated variable to the page.

```
$name = "blabla";
$name_en = "this is english blabla";
$locale = "_en";
echo $name.$locale;
```

it prints blabla_en instead of "this is english blabla"

Comment: What You are looking for is called a [Variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
$name = "blabla";
$name_en = "this is english blabla";
$locale = "_en";
echo ${'name'.$locale};  // set variable name as static string and locale suffix
```

A **better** solution is using `arrays`:

```
$messages = [
    'blabla' => [
        'de' => 'blabla',
        'en' => 'this is english blabla'
    ]
];
$locale = "en";
echo $messages['blabla'][$locale];
```